# Meteor download error (via curl)

Tags: curl, meteor

Just updated OSX el cap (10.11.4) after a HD failure and my Meteor instal is not working. Below is the error message that I am getting. 
What is the workaround for this?

```
$ curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6675    0  6675    0     0   1641      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--  1641
Downloading Meteor distribution
################################                                          45.4%
curl: (18) transfer closed with 90806516 bytes remaining to read
.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.lbyo5v++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/babel-preset-meteor/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/core-js/client/library.min.js: (Empty error message)
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Installation failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this problem is a geographical issue related to the Meteor CDN. It should be fixed by now. There is more info along with troubleshooting steps on the repo [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6960).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. Try to update curl and if you use a VPN (or a proxy), disable it before the installation. Also check if you have enough memory for the installation

Comment: How do you update curl? Also, there is some communication on [github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6960#issuecomment-216485324) that might help some people..

Comment: I just updated the answer in case you are still stuck.